# Bug with Photoswipe in jQuery Mobile? Popups not showing in certain cases

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

My photoswipe gallery works fine, I have only one issue:

Case1:
After entering #gallery on #about I can click on a photo, view and close it and hit the back button which brings me to #about. #about includes a popup image which can be viewed. This way everything works fine

Case2:
After entering #gallery on #about there are all available photos. But when I don't click one and just hit the back button, which brings me to #about the popup will not show, although the browsers url adds &ui-state=dialog to the url

This is very strange. Here's my photoswipe js code:

```
(function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.gallery-page')
        .live('pageshow', function(e){

            var 
                currentPage = $(e.target),
                options = {},
                photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

            return true;

        })

        .live('pagehide', function(e){

            var 
                currentPage = $(e.target),
                photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

            if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
            }

            return true;

        });

});

}(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

The

elements of photswipe will be added this way:

```
$('#galleryContent').append('<li><a href="XXX" rel="external"><img src="XXX" width="150"  /></a></li>');
```

This is the gallery:

```
<div data-role="page" id="gallery" class="gallery-page" data-add-back-btn="true">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Images</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">    

    <ul class="gallery" id="galleryContent">    
    </ul>

</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <h4>xxx</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I have this same problem. Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the master version of PhotoSwipe at https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe .

Download the master version and run the build.sh script to generate version 3.0.5.1.